# Object drops when teleporting

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, vrtk

I have a cardboard box that can be picked up by the player. I have set up a mesh collider on this box and now it keeps any items that get picked up by the other hand within. However, as soon as I teleport, the items within the box do not follow the new position. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

When you teleport (I assume you just change the transform position), it goes in that frame to that position, colliders and physics are ignored.
A simple way would be to make the cardboard box a child of the player as soon as you pick it up (most VR frameworks already do this), and then items that go inside the box a child of the box.